# What is the proper way to call Dispose() in a Quartz .NET IJob that is IDisposable?

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I want to include a `Timer` to call a timeout method on my `IJob`. Since `Timer` is Disposable, I made my `IJob` implement `IDispose`, but I'm not sure where to call `Dispose()` from, since `IJob` creation and destruction is handled by the scheduler.

Comment: Use the 'Using' statement on your IJob object. The 'Using' statement guarantees calling the 'Dispose' method.

Comment: @lcryder as OP said, the scheduler will be creating the object. I think the scheduler itself does the disposing in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one class that is responsible for all job creation, so I've implemented `IJobListener` on it, and registered it to listen for all jobs.

In `JobWasExecuted`, I've added the following toward the end of the method:

```
if (context.JobInstance.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyBaseJobType)))
{
    (context.JobInstance as MyBaseJobType).Dispose();
}
```

I have no idea if this is the "correct" way, but it seems to be working. I do not think the scheduler `Dispose()`s automatically, because prior to adding the above, my timer seemed to keep going after the job had completed; apparently it was keeping the job thread alive. Also, IJob doesn't implement `IDispose` itself, so IMHO expected behavior would not be for the scheduler to `Dispose`.

**EDIT:** Another thought was to `Dispose()` of the timer in the timer callback, and also at the end of `Execute()`. Thinking this through, though: if the `IJob` throws a `JobExecutionException`, it won't be properly disposed; so this is probably not a good option.

Comment: You can add a try/finally block in Execute method, and call dispose in the finally block. The finally block will also get called if an exception is thrown.